# replacing NaT with 0 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks lie:

```
A      
3 days    
NaT       
4 days
```

Is there a way to replace the NaT with 0 days ?

thanks,
Ed

Comment: `df.fillna(pd.Timedelta('0 days'))`

Comment: `df.fillna(0)` if `dtypes` are `timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: df.fillna(0) is deprecated (Passing integers to fillna is deprecated, will raise a TypeError in a future version.)

Answer (score 31):

Please note that the other answers are not up to date anymore. The preferred syntax is:

```py
df['column'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
```

The previously mentioned

```py
df['column'].fillna(0)
```

will results in:

> FutureWarning: Passing integers to fillna is deprecated, will raise a
>   TypeError in a future version.  To retain the old behavior, pass
>   pd.Timedelta(seconds=n) instead. df['column'] = df['column'].fillna(0)

Answer (score 12):

Another way will be to use .replace

```
d = {'A': ['3 days', '4 days', 'NaT']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.replace({'NaT': '0 day'}, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    A
0   3 days
1   4 days
2   0 day
```

Comment: Think NaT is not a string.

Comment: NaT is not a string...

Answer (score 9):

When trying to implement manoj's replace-based answer with version 0.24.1, I found that I had to use "pandas.NaT" rather than just the string "Nat":

```
import pandas as pd
...

df.replace({pd.NaT: "0 days"}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Great answer, especially since pd.np is being depreciated. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Building off of this, I simply turned the "0 days" into null values to sit in my db as Datetime types with this: `df.replace({pd.NaT: None}, inplace=True)`. Otherwise I got an error.

Answer (score 5):

```
df.A = pd.to_timedelta(df.A)
df.fillna(0)

       A
0 3 days
1 0 days
2 4 days
```