# Replacing NaNs with date and time format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, nan, timedelta

I'm working with the following dataframes.

```
    Date    Light (umols)   Time_difference
0   2018-01-12 07:16:52 2.5 NaT
1   2018-01-12 07:19:52 4.9 0 days 00:03:00
2   2018-01-12 07:22:52 4.9 0 days 00:03:00
3   2018-01-12 07:25:52 7.4 0 days 00:03:00
4   2018-01-12 07:28:50 9.9 0 days 00:02:58
... ... ... ...
6252    2018-12-18 17:54:24 12.2    0 days 00:03:00
6253    2018-12-18 17:57:24 7.6 0 days 00:03:00
6254    2018-12-18 18:00:24 4.9 0 days 00:03:00
6255    2018-12-18 18:03:24 2.5 0 days 00:03:00
6256    2018-12-18 18:06:24 0.2 0 days 00:03:00

    Date    Light (umols)   Time_difference
0   2019-01-10 00:00:00 500.4   NaT
1   2019-01-10 00:00:01 451.2   0 days 00:00:01
2   2019-01-10 00:00:02 343.7   0 days 00:00:01
3   2019-01-10 00:00:03 354.5   0 days 00:00:01
4   2019-01-10 00:00:04 176.4   0 days 00:00:00
... ... ... ...
81264   2021-02-22 23:59:55 937.7   0 days 00:00:00
81265   2021-02-22 23:59:56 634.4   0 days 00:00:00
81266   2021-02-22 23:59:57 574.3   0 days 00:00:00
81267   2021-02-22 23:59:58 598.9   0 days 00:00:00
81268   2021-02-22 23:59:59 676.9   0 days 00:00:00
```

I'm wanting to calculate where there are gaps, how long they are and how many there are. The idea is to have a consistent timeline every 3 minutes in a day tops, and anything above that needs to flagged up, the idea would be to merge the two dataframes together afterwards. There are some pesky NaTs in both their first rows, and I want to replace each one with something like '0 days 00:00:00'. I tried writing the following code with little success:

```
better = clean['Date'] == '2018-01-12 07:16:52'
clean.loc[better, 'Time_difference'] = clean.loc[clean, 'Time_difference'].replace('NaT', '0 days 00:00:00')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: to clarify: you want to fill `NaT` in a timedelta column (not datetime). you can simply do so by `df['Time_difference'] = df['Time_difference'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacing NaT with 0 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240881/replacing-nat-with-0-days)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you so much, that really helped!